# Find all $a$ such that $y=\log_\frac{1}{\sqrt3} (x-2a) = \log_3(x-2a^3-3a^2) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Find all values of parameter $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$y= \log_\frac{1}{\sqrt3} (x-2a)$$ $$and$$ $$y = \log_3(x-2a^3-3a^2)$$ intersect at points with **whole** coordinates.

This is what I did:
$$\log_\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(x-2a) = \frac{log_3(x-2a)}{\log_33^{-1/2}}$$

$$\frac{\log_3(x-2a)}{\log_33^{-1/2}} = \log_3(x-2a^3-3a^2)$$
$$-2\log_3(x-2a) = \log_3(x-2a^3-3a^2)$$
$$\log_3\frac{1}{(x-2a)^2} = \log_3(x-2a^3-3a^2)$$
$$\frac{1}{(x-2a)^2} = (x-2a^3-3a^2)$$

I got up to this point, not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: $3^y = (1/\sqrt{3})^{-2y}$

Comment: As for the 3rd step, you should be dividing by $-1/2$ instead of multiplying by $-1/2$ in the left-hand side, right? That is equivalent to multiplying by $-2$, which avoids the square root.

Comment: You can use change of base to get $\log_{b^m}  X = \frac {\log_b X}{\log_b b^m}=\frac 1m\log_b X = \log_b X^{\frac 1m}$.  Or you could figure $\log_{b^m} X = k$ then $b^{mk}=X$ so $\log_b X = mk$ and $k=\frac 1m\log_b X=\log_b X^{\frac 1m}$.  In either case $\log_{b^m} X = \log_b X^{\frac 1m}$ can be an identity.  So $\log_{\frac 1{\sqrt 3}}(x-2a) = \log_3 (x-2a)^{-2} =\log_3(x - 2a^3-3a^2)$ so $(x-2a)^{-2} = x-2a^3 - 3a^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting a common base, $3$, and exponentiating, we have
$$
\frac{1}{(x-2 a)^2} = -3 a^2 - 2 a^3 + x
$$Since we are requiring $a,x$ to be whole numbers, the RHS is an integer which means the LHS must be as well: then $x-2a=\pm 1$. However, since these came from logarithms, only the case $x-2a=1$ is allowed. Then the equation becomes $1=-3a^2-2a^3+1+2a$, whose solutions are $a=\{-2,0,1/2\}$.

So in summary, the point $(a,x)=(0,1)$ is the only whole number solution , and there is also the solution $(a,x)=(-2,-3)$ if one admits negative integers.

Comment: The question asks that $(x,y)$ be whole, not $(a,x)$. I think we should manually check whether $y$ is whole, or is it somehow already clear from the values of $a$ and $x$ ?

Comment: Oh, I guess the expression is always equal to 1... So $y$ has to be $0$, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.